# Can r.mask be called from a batch file?

Tags: grass-gis, masking

I am using a shell script that is called by a batch file. The shell script contains the GRASS scripts that I am using for my program. Every time I use the r.mask script, it displays the error `r.mask: command not found`.

Can r.mask be called from a batch file? How can I use r.mask using a batch file and shell script?

Answer (score 1):

A shell script called by a batch file? So you're running GRASS on a *nix box that is connected to a Windows box...

Either way, you need to ensure you have set up the environment correctly on whichever machine has GRASS installed. At the very least you need to ensure the PATH environment variable contains the directory in which the GRASS scripts can be found. On my Ubunutu machine, it's `/usr/lib/grass64/scripts/` but your installation may be different.

See [here](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Shell) for lots of useful information on setting up the GRASS environment and running shell scripts.

Comment: I already fixed my environment variables. My other scripts are working, except for the r.mask script

Comment: Hmmm... then I would be inclined to say it isn't there! If you're using Linux, type `locate r.mask` to see if it can find it, and you can also try `locate` with a script you know exists, and have a look in that directory. If you can't find it, then it's either been deleted, or you are running a version of GRASS that didn't come with that script, although I'm not sure if there are any versions like that.

Comment: The script could run if I run it in grass itself, but when I run it using the batch file, it does not run. All my scripts run (r.in.ascii, r.out.gdal, r.out.png, r.mapcalc, etc.) except for the r.mask.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that `r.mask` is a script, whereas the others are binaries, and so they live in a different place. So make sure you have the scripts directory added to your path. I'm on a SuSE box at the moment and the GRASS binaries are in `/opt/grass/bin/`, but the scripts are in `/opt/grass/scripts/` If you can run it from within GRASS then it must be somewhere on your system, so it's just a case of finding it and adding that directory to your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you work with winGRASS. If it is winGRASS 6, then try `r.mask.bat` or `r.mask.sh` to call it.